# Using justify-content: space-between; in nested flexbox

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to apply flexbox on the **header** tag and also apply flexbox on the **ul** tag which is inside the header tag (**nested flexbox**), for the outer flexbox **justify-content: space-between;** was used and it worked properly, however when using **justify-content: space-between;"** for the inner flexbox too it doesn't do anything, I was expecting it to seperate each navbar list item with some space in between like it did for the outer flexbox, it can be achieved using **margin** but why is using **justify-content: space-between;"** not working like it did for the outer flexbox?.

JSX

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import classes from "./Navbar.module.css";

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <header className={classes.header}>
      <div>Logo</div>
      <nav className={classes.nav}>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="./">Home</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="./">News</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="./">Contact</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="./">About</NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

CSS

```
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  padding: 0 10%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both flex boxes are technically working as intended.

They are not giving you the desired layout by default, because the flex-item parent `nav` of the inner flex container got no inherent "width" information other than inner flex items text content.

3 possible solutions:

1. parent of inner flex continer `<nav>`: set fixed or relative `width`
2. inner flex items `<li>`: set fixed `width` or `flex-basis`
3. inner flex items `<li>`: add some appropriate spacing

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `width` to `nav`, i.e. the parent of the flex `ul`, otherwise both of these will only use just the space of it's contents (i.e. all `li`s without any distance between them), and therefore `justify-content` won't be effective at all.

I added 40% width in my edit of your code below - tha's enough to demontrate the effect of `justify-content: space-between`, but adjust that as needed. Note that I also removed the default padding from the `ul` and used `box-sizing: border-box;` on everything to include the padding into the width to not let the page overflow horizontally in the snippet.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  padding: 0 10%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

nav {
  width: 40%;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header className={classes.header}>
  <div>Logo</div>
  <nav className={classes.nav}>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <NavLink to="./">Home</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink to="./">News</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink to="./">Contact</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink to="./">About</NavLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

that is because there is no space available for the nav links to take.
the parent flex divides the space available to be equal for the two items.
so to achieve what you want, you need to define the spaces of each part.

one way to achieve that is to use `flex-grow`.

```
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  padding: 0 10%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

// here I give the logo equal size of space as the nav
// you can change the values whatever you desire.

div {
  flex-grow: 4  //div for logo
}

nav {
  flex-grow: 4
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```